# Diferente resultados 'count(*) from V$ASM_DISK'

Tags: sql, oracle, linux, oracle11g

Tenho um script que se conecta em uma base Oracle e efetua o seguinte select:

```
select count(*) from V$ASM_DISK;
```

Esse script fica em um arquivo .sql, ai efetuo a seguinte chamada no SO:

```
"$ORA_HOME/bin/sqlplus -L -S xxxx/xxxx @query.sql";
```

Ao Executar o Script como *root*, o resultado é 0, porem ao executar a mesma query como usuario *oracle*, o retorno é diferente.

Ambos os usuarios efetuam o mesmo login no Oracle.

Não estou conseguindo achar o motivo dessa diferença no retorno.

Comment: imagino que o *root* consiga ler o script, claro, mas quando você usa o sqlplus pra só logar usando o *root*, sem executar o script, ele te dá um prompt do oracle?